# For a project dealing with ERDs and coding it in sql database tables and I am having trouble with foreign keys. This is for a project due tomorrow

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Create table Workers
(WorkerID int not null, 
Name varchar(30)not null, 
DateHired Date not null, 
Termination date , 
employmentStatus varchar(25) not null , 
salary int not null, 
OfficeLocation varchar(30) not null, 
Street varchar(30) not null , 
City varchar(30) not null, 
State varchar(30) not null, 
WorkerType archer(30) not null,
sub_workerID int references workers(WorkerID)  null,
constraint workers_pk primary key (WorkerID));

--drop sub_workerID from workers

--drop table workers

--insert workers
insert into Workers values 
(102,'JAntonio Brown', '2010-01-21','','current',99355,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','E',102),
(103,'Charles Xavier', '2010-01-12','','current',94555,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','M',103);

insert into Workers values (104,'Charles Xavier', '2010-01-03','','current',99995,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','M',104),
(105,'MRatt EKl', '2010-01-14','','current',83555,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','M',105);

insert into Workers values (106,'Charles saveer', '2010-01-10','','current',33395,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','E',106),
(107,'keaton gomez', '2010-01-12','','current',83675,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','M',107);

insert into Workers values (108,'Chappy William', '2010-01-16','','current',65555,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','E',108),
(109,'Aryan GH', '2010-01-15','','current',54655,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','M',109);

insert into Workers values (110,'Charles Xavier', '2010-01-17','','current',99545,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','M',110),
(111,'Mark Mathom', '2010-01-18','','current',22555,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','M',111);

insert into Workers values (112,'Charlie Parker', '2010-01-20','','current',34595,'campus 1', '55 1st','dc','dc','E',112);



   --------
    create table Subscription
    (SubscriptionID varchar(30) not null,
    Subsciption_Name varchar(30) not null,
    Premium_level varchar(30) not null,
    Offerer varchar(30) not null,
    Price int not null,
    constraint Subscription_pk primary key (SubscriptionID));

--insert subscription
INSERT INTO Subscription VALUES ('MS',          'MSOffice ','   SaaS','Microsoft    ',      20);
INSERT INTO Subscription VALUES ('Zoho',            'Zoho Books','  SaaS    ','     Zoho Corp   ',      8);

INSERT INTO Subscription VALUES ('GitHub',          'GitHub ',' Enterprise','       Microsoft',         2000);

INSERT INTO Subscription VALUES ('LinkedIn',        'LinkedIn','    Recruiter   ',' LinkedIn Corp',         100);

INSERT INTO Subscription  VALUES ('Slack    ',      'Slack  ',' Enterprise  ',' Slack Tech',            9);

select * from subscription

-------
create table Account 
(UserID varchar(10)  not null,
Passwords varchar(30) not null,
WorkerID int not null, --references Workers(WorkerID) not null, 
SubscriptionID varchar(30) not null, --references Subscription(SubscriptionID) not null);
constraint account_pk primary key (WorkerID,subscriptionID),
constraint account_fk2 foreign key (WorkerID) references Workers(WorkerID),
constraint account_fk1 foreign key (subscriptionID) references Subscription(SubscriptionID));

--constraint Account_pk primary key (UserID));
--drop table account;
--insert account
INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('101JS','     dal;kjsfio23', 101,'        MS');

INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('102AB','     wipuertOU32', 102,' MS');

INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('104CX','     QWRas12sd', 104 ,'  MS');

INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('106EM','     DSAF976asad',106,'      MS');

INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('107TD','     wertiou976234s', 107    ,'  MS');

INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('108LF','     AW#ZSE$iw3', 108    ,'  MS');

INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('109KL','     dsfhkj9867asds ',109,'      MS');

INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('110NC','     sadwe432a334 ',110  ,'  MS');

INSERT INTO Account(UserID,Passwords,WorkerID,SubscriptionID) VALUES ('111SP','     asdfgf746Eouy', 111,' MS');
```

It Gives me this message when using the insert into accounts, and I really don't know how to fix is as I have tried for hours on.
**Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 120
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "account_fk1". The conflict occurred in database "EllisCIS330", table "dbo.Subscription", column 'SubscriptionID'.**

Comment: There are lots of leading spaces here. Why? Also, is this really MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting records into the Account table that include a subscription id that doesn't exist in the subscription table.

In the account insert you have ' MS' for the subscription id i.e. there is an incorrect leading space